# How to use Previously data

Tags: rules, thingsboard, chain

I have a data which is ı collected from sensors. I wanna calculate like this: I'll take this depth data, and then ı'll wait for a 30 seconds (problem starts here) ı write this code:

var previousShiftDepthProgress = 0;

var currentShiftProcess = totalMassDP;

var shiftProgress = currentShiftProcess - previousShiftDepthProgress;

previousShiftDepthProgress = currentShiftProcess;

every 30 seconds ı calculate somethings. But this code doesnt work. Because every -ı set for 30 seconds- shift everthings gets restart and does not store data, so thats why ı couldnt use previously data. I stucked here. What am ı missing? I use a rule chain and this code is in blue script. İs there any way to do this on another rule in the rule chain. Suggestions?

Thanks.

I looked Use data-processing function and rule chain but ı couldnt find.